# An error occurs after replacing a variable value to a new one

Tags: assembly, memory, nasm, x86-16, addressing-mode

When changing the value of a variable an error occurs `invalid effective address`.

```
mov bl, var
mov [bl], 'a'
mov al, [bl] <--- here
mov ah, 0x0E
int 0x10

var db 'H'
```

As I know `al` is 8-bit and `bl` is a pointer pointing to 8-bit memory size.
There is something wrong that occurred after assigning a new value to `var`, **I don't know why**?

---

Code after debugging:

```
mov bx, var
mov byte [var], 'a'
mov al, byte [bx]
mov ah, 0x0E
int 0x10

var db 'H'
```

Comment: No, `bl` *is* an 8-bit register, and you're trying to use it as a pointer, but x86 doesn't support 8-bit address-size.  (8-bit operand-size is fine, but pointers are 16 bits wide in real mode).  You should be getting an error on `mov [bl], 'a'` as well, about ambiguous operand-size as well as invalid address-size.

Comment: Interestingly, NASM does let you `mov bl, var` to put the low 8 bits of the address into BL, maybe only warning about that if the address happens to be >= 0xff?  But if you want to deref it, you should `mov bx, var`

Comment: @PeterCordes: Is my code correct now [My Code](https://i.ibb.co/qdcK8Zd/20211021-044034.png)? (It's working)

Comment: Yeah, looks fine.  You could of course just use `[var]` if you don't want to put the address into a register first, like a C compiler would (for 32-bit mode) if you wrote `var = 'a'` / `return var;` in a function.

Comment: @LionKing Do not post links to external paste sites please.  Instead [edit] your post and add your new code.

Comment: @Peter Cordes: I found two NASM bug reports about specifying labels in byte-sized contexts: [1](https://bugzilla.nasm.us/show_bug.cgi?id=3392678) and especially [2](https://bugzilla.nasm.us/show_bug.cgi?id=3392655) with a reply by hpa, a NASM developer.